# How to organize my own angular 1.x modules in my project (I'm using typescript)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript, directory-structure

I'm writing an angular app for which I need to create a few angular modules (read services and directives). The thing is I want them to be ***re-usable*** and hopefully installable in my other projects using `bower`.

*Example:* Let's say I'm creating these two directives for my angular project (with PHP as backend). This is only for example, I'll be creating many such modules actually.

1. Angular image enhancer (angular-image-enhancer *directive*)
2. Angular session manager (angular-sesion-mananger *service*)

The structure of my app is something like this

`app
   model
   view
   controller
     Homepage.php
 public
   static
      bower_components
        angular
          angular.js
        jquery
 vendor
   composer
   symfony
   monolog
   (other php modules)`

**Question #1:** In which directory should I store the AngularJs modules I'm creating? Should I create `angular-image-enhancer` directory under `public > static > bower_components`?

**Question #2:** I want these modules that I'm creating to be imported in my other projects using `bower` like `bower install angular-image-enhancer` (i.e. use bower to install them during project deployment also)

**Question #3:** I'm using Typescript to write my angular modules. How can I make it so that I can have `src` and `dist` folders with my `.ts` files in the `angular-image-enhancer > src` folder and compiled js files ***automatically*** put in the `angular-image-enhancer > dist` folder respectively?

P.S. I'm using `PhpStorm` in case that matters to anyone.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here are my suggestions:

While the MVC folder structure seems appealing it lacks portability when it comes to big angular projects. A better way would be to use directory per module. That way you can easily navigate **and** reuse components later.

Obviously these files are static so they can be stored in the static folder.

For your modules to be available through bower you'll have to [register](https://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#register) them with bower.

I have no experience with typescript unfortunately.